# Вычисление innerHTML по ряду таблицы и ID ячейки

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

[image: img]

Дорогие гуру, есть табличка при клики на ячейку нужно чтобы значение (`innerHTML`) вписалось в форму ( `<input type="text" id="идячейки" или name="идячейки">` ).

У меня есть `id` столбца ( `<td id="ид">` ) и индекс `<tr>`: ( `row.sectionRowIndex` ). Обработчик клика есть, подскажите код вычисления значения и записать в форму. Заранее премного благодарен.

Таблицу генерит php принципи можно задать и `id` и `<tr>` если это как то поможет.

С уважением, Олег.

Всё оказалось намного проще:

```
document.getElementById(ид таблицы).rows[ид td].cells[ид tr].innerText
```

Всем удачи.

Comment: только пользуйте innerHTML, ибо innerText при определенных условиях может не сработать

Comment: Спасибо, а при каких если не секрет?
И вообще в javascript не очень силен, скажите пожалуйста на сколько корректна такая конструкция:

document.getElementById('atip').value = document.getElementById(tableId).rows[row.sectionRowIndex].cells['tip'].innerHTML.substr(0, 1);

на большинстве браузерах (ie7+,ff,chrome,opera) работает вроде норм....

Comment: ИЕ6-7 и файрфокс .иннертекст не жалуют...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так можно получить все td в ряду на котором кликнули (элементы td будут в массиве elements), [тут можно запустить рабочий пример](http://learn.javascript.ru/play/75rG2b)  . вам только остается перебрать массив и перенести данные в поля

```
var table = document.getElementById("tstTB");

      table.onclick = function (e){

        var target =  event.srcElement || e.target, elements;
        var parent = target.parentNode;

        while(parent.tagName != "TR" && parent )
        {

          parent = parent.parentNode;

        }

        elements = parent.getElementsByTagName("td");// все элементы td

      };
```